# Derailleur does not match up with chain after tube replacement

Tags: chain, derailleur-rear, rear-wheel

I have been recently replacing rear inner tube on my bike, since then I was not able to fix the
wheel back in.

It makes unusual clicking sounds when backpedaling and one side of the chain gets loose. Upon further inspection I think the problem is that the chain does not properly fit into the rear cogwheels, as if the chain got longer while replacing the wheel?

Also, if I shift to the smallest cogwheel on rear derailleur, the part with two small wheels gets collapsed as if there was not enough tension making in practically impossible to function.

[image: collapsed rear derailleur]

As I said, the bike was working perfectly. I only took out the rear wheel, replaced inner tube and put the wheel back in.

Here is a video of me trying to backpedal. Also notice how the part of the derailleur is wobbling - it is because the chain seems not to fit in the teeth and causes resistance.

Comment: Are you sure you got the wheel properly seated and centered when you reinstalled it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this was a pre-existing condition in your drivetrain that you just didn't notice before removing the wheel. Have you tried riding the bike and seeing if it functions as before, when the right way up and pedalling forward?

There does seem to be resistance in the jockey wheels in the derailleur cage. You can try removing, cleaning and re-lubricating them.

Comment: Well I rode the bike every few days before replacement without any problem so I do not think this was a pre-existing condition? I may have bumped the derailleur accidentaly while replacing the wheel though.

Comment: Oh! So I tried it the right way up and it actually worked, the problem was pre-existing however this issue only happens when bike is on the smallest cogwheel on the front and smallest on the back which is a combination I never use when riding. What do you suggest I should do anyway to fix it? Replace the chain?

Comment: I'd definitely look at the jockey wheels, a really good clean an re-lube of the chain may help. The chain might be a couple of links too long, but it's hard to tell from the photo and video.